# How to efficiently fetch n most recent rows with GROUP BY in sqlite?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have a table of event results, and I need to fetch the most recent n events per player for a given list of players.

This is on iOS so it needs to be fast. I've looked at a lot of top-n-per-group solutions that use subqueries or joins, but these run slow for my 100k row dataset even on a macbook pro. So far my dumb solution, since I will only run this with a maximum of 6 players, is to do 6 separate queries. It isn't terribly slow, but there has to be a better way, right? Here's the gist of what I'm doing now:

```
results_by_pid = {} 
player_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
n_results = 6
for pid in player_ids:
  results_by_pid[pid] = exec_sql("SELECT * 
                                  FROM results
                                  WHERE player_id = #{pid}
                                  ORDER BY event_date DESC
                                  LIMIT n_events")
```

And then I go on my merry way. But how can I turn this into a single fast query?

Comment: There is no better way. SQLite is designed as an *embedded* database where most of the logic stays in the application. Why do you want it to be a single query?

Comment: There's io overhead in making separate calls to sqlite, so in general isn't minimizing total queries best if possible?

Comment: In general, yes. But not if you then have to go through contortions that make the end result clearly worse.

Comment: Fair enough. My sql-fu isn't all that strong, so I was hoping that some complex query that's beyond me to construct could accomplish this more efficiently.

Comment: @CL By the way, feel free to add that as an answer--I'll mark it accepted after a bit if no one comes up with anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way.
SQL window functions, which might help, are not implemented in SQLite.

SQLite is designed as an embedded database where most of the logic stays in the application.
In contrast to client/server databases where network communication should be avoided, there is no performance disadvantage to mixing SQL commands and program logic.

A less dumb solution requires you to do some `SELECT player_id FROM somewhere` beforehand, which should be no trouble.

To make the individual queries efficient, ensure you have one index on the two columns `player_id` and `event_date`.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be much of an answer, but here goes...

I have found that making things really quick can involve ideas from the nature of the data and schema themselves. For example, searching an ordered list is faster than searching an unordered list, but you have to pay a cost up front - both in design and execution.

So ask yourself if there are any natural partitions on your data that may reduce the number of records SQLite must search. You might ask whether the latest n events fall within a particular time period. Will they all be from the last seven days? The last month? If so then you can construct the query to rule out whole chunks of data before performing more complex searches.

Also, if you just can't get the thing to work quickly, you can consider UX trickery! Soooooo many engineers don't get clever with their UX. Will your query be run as the result of a view controller push? Then set the thing going in a background thread from the PREVIOUS view controller, and let it work while iOS animates. How long does a push animation take? .2 seconds? At what point does your user indicate to the app (via some UX control) which `playerids` are going to be queried? As soon as he touches that button or TVCell, you can prefetch some data. So if the total work you have to do is *O(n log n)*, that means you can probably break it up into *O(n)* and *O(log n)* pieces.

Just some thoughts while I avoid doing my *own* hard work.

---

***More thoughts***

How about a separate table that contains the ids of the previous n inserts? You could add a trigger to delete old ids if the size of the table grows above n. Say..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recent_results
   (result_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_date DATE);
// is DATE a type? I don't know. you get the point

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS optimizer
   AFTER INSERT ON recent_results
   WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recent_results) > N
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM recent_results
      WHERE result_id = (SELECT result_id
                         FROM recent_results
                         WHERE event_date = MIN(event_date));
// or something like that. I have no idea if this will work,
// I just threw it together.
```

Or you could just create a temporary memory-based table that you populate at app load and keep up to date as you perform transactions during app execution. That way you only pay the steep price once!

Just a few more thoughts for you. Be creative, and remember that you can usually define what you want as a data structure as well as an algorithm. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! While I can't think of much I can do with regard to db architecture (the last n events could fall in any time period), there's definitely a point in the flow where I could start prefetching the data a bit sooner to improve the ux. Otoh, if I can get a fast query, I won't need to bother :P